# El fichero no se renombra correctamente y no me valida

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, binario

estoy haciendo un ejercicio con ficheros en C, y lo último que me falta es poder eliminar las companias que el usuario me pide. Tengo una estructura donde guardo el **nombre de la compania y el pais**. Obviamente estos datos me los voy inventando para probar.

Tenia que hacer varias funciones, entre ellas una que es **modificar la compania**, y me lo hace perfectamente, pero el eliminar me esta dando muchos problemas que no entiendo.

Lo que tenia que hacer con esta función es coger la compania que quiere eliminar el usuario, comprobar que esta exista y si no que de un error, si no es así antes de todo creo un fichero auxiliar donde iran todos los datos que no se quieren eliminar y al final de todo despues de cerrar los ficheros elimino el fichero original y renombro el auxiliar con el nombre original.

Pero cada rato me lo hace diferente, una vez me lo elimina bien, de otros en el que en la carpeta me sigue generando el fichero auxiliar, es decir, no me lo renombra ni me mete nada y de otras que me dice que la compania no existe cuando si que existe.

**Dudo que el error sea en la función de existeCompania ya que con modificar,introducir ha funcionado.**

```
void eliminarcompania(){
    char cadenaAux[MAXCADENA];
    FILE *f,*fNuevo;
    f=fopen("companyies.dat","rb");
    fNuevo=fopen("companyiesAUX.dat","wb");
    bool eliminado=false;
    tCompanyia CompElim;

    printf("Introduce la compania que quieres eliminar: ");
    scanf("%s",cadenaAux);

    if(existeCompania(cadenaAux)){
        fread(&CompElim,sizeof(tCompanyia),1,f);
        while(feof(f)==0){
            if(strcmpi(CompElim.nomComp,cadenaAux)==0 && !eliminado){
                eliminado=true;
            }else{
                fwrite(&CompElim,sizeof(tCompanyia),1,fNuevo);
            }
            fread(&CompElim,sizeof(tCompanyia),1,f);
        }
        fclose(f);
        fclose(fNuevo);
        remove("companyies.dat");
        rename("companyiesAUX.dat","companyies.dat");
    }else{
        printf("La compania %s no se puede eliminar porque no existe",cadenaAux);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas, hay situaciones en las que no se cierran los archivos:

```
if(existeCompania(cadenaAux)){
    // ...
    fclose(f);
    fclose(fNuevo);
}else{
    // AQUI!!!
    printf("La compania %s no se puede eliminar porque no existe",cadenaAux);
}
```

No puedes eliminar un archivo si lo tienes abierto, luego tu programa presumiblemente fallará en el momento en el que muestre el mensaje de que la compañía no existe.

La solución es simple: garantiza el cierre de los recursos:

```
if(existeCompania(cadenaAux)){
    // Estos close ya no sirven
    // fclose(f);
    // fclose(fNuevo);
}else{
    printf("La compania %s no se puede eliminar porque no existe",cadenaAux);
}

fclose(f);
fclose(fNuevo);
```

Comment: ostras no lo había visto, voy a probarlo. Pero el rename y el remove deberia de cambiarlos junto con los close tambien ?

Comment: No se porque, la primera vez me ha dicho que la compania no existe cuando si y luego me lo ha eliminado. Pero despues de varias pruebas añadiendo y modificando, me ha generado otra vez en la carpeta el archivo AUX no se pq. No veo el fallo

Comment: No puedo depurar tu código.  Verifica los retornos de `rename` y `remove`. Comprueba que no te dejas el archivo abierto en otro punto del código... depura paso a paso...

Comment: Eso he probado tambien. Yo utilizo el codeblocks y por alguna razón cuando pongo un punto de interrumpción no me muestra nada, ni ningún error. No se que hacer.

Comment: @Wail para que los puntos de interrupción funcionen tienes que compilar en modo debug.

Comment: Soy consciente de ello, es un fallo que nos ha pasado a varios compañeros. No se si recomiendas otro ide mejor para C? El codeblocks me da muchos problemas.

Comment: @Wail prueba con qt creator. Es un buen ide que se integra muy bien con gcc y mingwin